# VREG output circuitry

Tags: power-supply

I am making a PCB and I want the ability to have multiple power sources for it. One is a DC barrel jack and another is a transformer/rectifier.

In the past I would use jumpers to allow one power circuit to be totally disconnected while the other connects, or vice versa. I'm wondering if this is necessary though because I will need to break up some power planes and have less optimal routing on my current design to accomplish this.

My board has a separate regulator for each power source. I would like to have the outputs of each regulator tied together and have either one or the other  power the circuit. Is it bad for a simple linear regulator or LDO to have voltage present at its output while the regulator input is left floating/disconnected?

I have seen some other designs use Schottky diodes in series with the outputs, but I'd rather not lose the 0.3V after the regulator output.

I will never have a situation where it is powered by both sources at once, so one regulator will always be off (its input floating). Is it bad to tie the regulator outputs together in this situation or should I use jumpers to totally isolate them from each other?

Edit: Initial searches only led to discussions of paralleling regulators for increased current, but I recently saw this post:
[Can the outputs of 3 different voltage regulators be tied together?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/36950/can-the-outputs-of-3-different-voltage-regulators-be-tied-together?rq=1)

It has been stated in that thread that the regulators could be damaged, but not much explanation why.

Thanks in advance,
Pansy

Comment: Some LDOs incorporate a diode in the output, so if Vout is above Vin, it doesn't care. Look through the datasheets to determine if one has this functionality.

Comment: Why don't you have a common regulator that both sources can feed into then you can use steering diodes.

Comment: I agree with Andy that a single regulator from multiple sources is elegant, but if you must use separate regulators , then ideal diodes would do the job. http://www.linear.com/products/powerpath_controllers_*_ideal_diodes

Comment: @ Daniel, I don't know that we can say the output is above the input if the input is floating. Its voltage is undefined. I have external diodes from output to input on each regulator, but this is more to protect from the input being shorted, not floated.

Comment: You need some means of switching the input, otherwise if both power sources are available you either get both trying to feed the circuit, and you don't know which one (e.g. if you use diode steering, it's whichever regulator output is higher and could even oscillate between the two due to loading down the regulators if their outputs are very close, or due to a feedback effect). So you really want either manual switching of the input supply, or an automatic switching circuit which gives one input precedence over the other (e.g. if mains is available always use that).

Comment: "My board has a separate regulator for each power source." - why?

Comment: @ Andy aka, Yes, that is a simple solution. I did not explain my project thoroughly enough. I wanted to have isolated analog and digital sections of the board with only a ground connections at the ADC and DAC. In the end for long term use I wanted to use a transformer with dual secondary outputs and have each tap power a separate regulator for each section. I wanted the DC jack for initial testing and debugging. I overlooked the fact that I would need to connect my ground planes at the supply as well for the DC jack to work. I need to rethink things. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ Peter Smith, I had never seen a chip like those "ideal" diode ones you linked. They seem to be more for hot swapping but one datasheet I looked at did mention a situation where one input voltage was disconnected. Interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your architecture doesn't make sense from what you are saying.  Combine the two power sources before the regulator, not after.  The transformer with full wave rectifier already can't be back-driven due to the diodes.  All you need is a Schottky diode in series with the DC barrel connector.  That's a good idea anyway to avoid damage when someone plugs in a wall wart with different polarity.

Combine the output of these two power sources right there.  Now you only need a single regulator, which gets around the awkward combining of the power after it's already at the final voltage.  If the wall wart and transformer output voltages vary a lot, use a switching buck converter.  Those can remain efficient over a much wider input voltage range.  If you really need extra clean linearly regulated final voltage, have the switcher make a few 100 mV more than what you need and use LDOs at the point of use.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Diodes you can easily put a mosfet at the output of every regulator (if you really must have serveral regulators). In this case you have (virtually) no voltage drop on the selector, assuming mosfets with very low Rds(on).
Special care has to be taken if both sources could be powered at the same time.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Your answer is too short to be of any use to the OP. There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar if you wish to add a schematic to explain your idea.